# MatLab: Plotting nested structures. Does a more efficient way of plotting than for-loops exist?

Tags: matlab, plot, nested, structure

I would like to know if how I'm plotting my data is an efficient way to go about it. Is this the case? Or does a different way exist, where I create the Structs and then create the plots outside of the for-loop in one go?

#### What I do:

Multiple plots per day per Rats. And I check for arrays which are not filled with zeroes, those arrays are not interesting. I have the values stored in a nested struct, which I build as follows:

```
for Rat = vecRat(1):vecRat(end)   
    for Day = UserDayArray 
        % I Build an array with Timediff here, which I left out for clarity
        Subject(Rat).day(Day). Timediff = Timediff;
        if isempty(Subject(Rat).day(Day).CumTimediff) == 0 && max((Subject(Rat).day(Day).CumTimediff)) ~= 0 && min((Subject(Rat).day(Day).CumTimediff)) ~=0
           stem(Subject(Rat).day(Day). Timediff)   %plots data
           end

        %Tells User that for this day no shaped trials were found.
        elseif isempty(Subject(Rat).day(Day).CumTimediff) == 0              
        fprintf(['****************** TSBP ', num2str(Rat), ' Day ', num2str(Day),'******************\n']);
        fprintf('No Shaping algorythm present/No Timechange detected\n');
        fprintf('No plots made\n');
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With combinations of 'cellfun', logical indexing and struct dereferencing this is what I came up with. Dont know your exact datastructure but this should work.

```
alldays=Subject(vecRat(1):vecRat(end)).day
AllCumTimediff={alldays(UserDayArray).CumTimediff}
%Use nested cellfun using the all and eq functions to check which plots can be made
%all([])=true so check for isempty to
plotsNotToUse=cellfun(@all,cellfun(@eq,AllCumTimediff,repmat({0},1,numel(AllCumTimediff)),'UniformOutput',false))
%Call your plotter and message functions
cellfun(@myplotter,AllCumTimediff(~plotsNotToUse))
cellfun(@myemptyMessage,AllCumTimediff(plotsNotToUse))


%%
function myplotter(CumTimediff)
figure; % create new figure
plot(CumTimediff);
%Whatever other commands
```

Comment: I've never used cellfun, so this is going to be very interesting. I think I understand what you are doing here, allthough I need to practice it. Two questions do arise, online I've read that cellfun is quite inefficient, so could this be slower than what I have?  And How should I go about with the plots? I use  plot(stuff i want to plot) but with the cellfun, I can't do that, or I don't know how

Comment: I just realised, naturally its going to be slower, because it allows for callback after the fact. So now all I really need is how do I make use of the @myplotter function, I'm not sure how to use that. Could you help?

Comment: This might not be the neatest answer.